# Magento2.3 - get product collection in stock only

Tags: magento2, product-collection

Magento 2 get product collection with filter `stock`

get only `in stock` product in the collection

**See below code**

```
$collection =  $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$this->_stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get only "in stock" product in the collection using following way:

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param Context           $context           [description]
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->productCollection = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /*Get in stock product collection*/
        $collection = $this->productCollection->create()->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false)
            ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', 'is_in_stock=1');
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($collection->getData());
        exit();
    }
}
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

By default magento filters only in stock products in collection

```
// $this->productCollection is object of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 $collection = $this->productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
```

> if you want to get out of stock products in collection then use

```
$collection = $this->productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false)
->load();
```

Comment: no it is not working I am using  "Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory" AND "Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" get all product

Comment: which magento version you used i tested this code in magento 2.3.3 it's working in my case

Comment: Magento version - 2.2.7 EE

Comment: hello @bharat i am also check above code in Magento 2.3.1 EE and its working also check in Magento 2.2.7.

$collection = $this->productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
this gives only in stock product collection

Answer (score 1):

You Can also try like this for Better Understandably and Readability:-

```
$collection->joinField('is_in_stock',
            'cataloginventory_stock_item',
            'is_in_stock',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            [],
            'left');
```